# OpenLaszlo DHTML InputText issue with clickthrough in Firefox 15

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

For some reason i am not able to enter any text in inputtext in dhtml environment. The same is working fine in swf10 environment.

When i hover over the input text i observed that the cursor is not changing to selector. It looks as if the onmouseover event of inputtext is not getting fired.

Has anyone come across this kind of issue in openlaszlo dhtml envrironment?

I am using OpenLaszlo 4.9, Windows 7 and the browser is Firefox 15.0

I found a bug report in jira http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-9934.

Please suggest any ideas to overcome this issue/

Comment: If you have problems connected to a specific browser in DHTML runtime, could you always add the OpenLaszlo version information and operating system you are using? You can retrieve that information through the context menu in the debug mode, by selecting 'Show Version Information'.

Comment: Modified the title to contain more information about the problem.

Comment: @RajuBitter: I am using OL 4.9, Windows 7 and the browser is Firefox 15.0

Comment: Using the test case attached to the [JIRA issue LPP-9934](http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-9934) with OpenLaszlo 5.0 revision 19765 everything is working fine in Firefox Linux 16.0.1 and in Firefox 15.0.1 on Windows 7. Only Chrome has problems displaying the text in the inputtext fields. Did you test your app with 5.0? I think that bug has not been fixed in 4.9 then.

Comment: @RajuBitter: Ok I will check that revision. Any information about this in android platform and ios platform?

Comment: I haven't done any testing with Android lately, and I don't have access to an Android device at the moment.

Comment: @RajuBitter: Ok..I'll try with both the versions in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is probably connected to the way OpenLaszlo replicates the behavior of clicking through Sprites or visual elements in the Flash runtime for the DHTML/JavaScript runtime. Until recently browsers didn't support that kind of functionality directly. Therefore the OpenLaszlo team had to use a workaround, which is described in detail [in this comment on LPP-5447](http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-5447?focusedCommentId=53019&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#action_53019).

> Clickdivs exist to have independent control over clickable sprites, 
>   without interference from regular divs. They are placed in a separate 
>   copy of the regular lzdiv sprite hierarchy so we have more control. 
>   This also provides a place to put focused inputtext divs so they are
>   in  the foreground and clicking/dragging to edit works properly.

The clickdiv functionality seems to be broken from time to time with browser updates or due to regressions. In 2012 [some improvements to the DHTML runtime click-through functionality](http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-10225) were done, using newer browser features in Firefox (which now allows to click through div elements using the CSS style `pointer-events`). Since the clickdiv functionality is part of the LFC, fixing that functionality in your application is not advised.

You can test if the inputtext works by tabbing through the components until your inputtext element has the focus and start typing. If the text can be entered as expected, but you cannot click the component with your mouse to select it, it's definitely a clickdiv problem.

**Update: Tested with OpenLaszlo 4.9.0 and various browsers**
I've tested with OpenLaszlo 4.9.0, DHTML runtime and IE9, Firefox as well as Chrome, using the test case attached to LPP-9934: All browsers show that specific bug behavior. If the bug has not been filed, please file a JIRA bug.